# Gaussian mixed model in small area estimation using P-splines

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, generalized-additive-model, mgcv, small-area-estimation

I am working  on a Fay-Herriot model in a small area estimation problem
\begin{equation}
y_d = X_d \beta + u_d + e_d
\end{equation}
where $y_d$ is a direct estimator of a certain parameter $\theta_d$, referred to a certain small area / cluster $d$, $d=1, \ldots, D$; $e_d \sim N(0, \psi_d)$, where $\psi_d$, the sampling variance, is known. $u_d \sim N(0, \sigma_u^2)$ are the small area random effects, whose variance is unknown. The model variance in matrix form is $V = X \sigma_u^2 X^T + \psi$.

This model, which is basically a Gaussial mixed model, typically uses a EBLUP estimator, where $\sigma_u^2$ is estimated by REML.
The predicted EBLUP is
\begin{equation}
\hat \theta_d^{EBLUP} = X_d^T \hat \beta + \frac{\hat \sigma_u^2}{\hat \sigma_u^2 + \psi_d}(y_d - X_d^T \hat \beta)
\end{equation}

Now, since my parameter is extremely nonlinear, I want to introduce some non-linearity and so relate it to P-splines, so that I penalize some random effects, $Z\gamma$, but I keep having a small area effect. So that the resulting model is
\begin{equation}
y_d = X_d \beta + Z\gamma + D_du_d + e_d
\end{equation}
where we suppose that $\gamma \sim N(0, \sigma_\gamma)$
I know that P-splines are related to random effect model, particularly if you use as smoothing parameter $\lambda = \sigma^2_e / \sigma_u^2$. The new model has variance $V = Z \Sigma_\gamma Z^T + D \Sigma_u D^T + \psi$

I am wondering if there is a way to fit this model using `mgcv` or other packages on R so that $\beta$ is estimated as $\hat \beta = (X^T V^{-1}X)^{-1}X^TV^{-1}y$, small area random effects are also estimtaed by EBLUP and my final predicted value is
\begin{equation}
\hat \theta_d^{EBLUP} = X_d^T \hat \beta + \frac{Z \hat \Sigma_\gamma Z^T + D \hat \Sigma_u D^T}{Z \hat \Sigma_\gamma Z^T + D \hat \Sigma_u D^T + \psi}(y_d - X_d^T \hat \beta)
\end{equation}
So that I want to treat the splines part as random effect plus add a small area effect.

How can I do that on R efficiently, considering that I have many variance components to estimate?